# How to catch angularfire2 error

Tags: angular, angularfire2

I am trying to add to a firebase database.
It adds all well and I get success in my promise then function.
However when I intentionally try to throw and error, then .catch callback doesn't log any error. Instead it refreshes the page.

Here is my component :

```
 submitForm(value: any){
    this._someService.listPlaces(pName.value, pCategory.value, pAddress.value, this.lat, this.lng)
    .then(_ => console.log('success'))
    .catch(err => console.log(err, 'Failed!'));
  }
```

And here is my _someService service :

```
listPlaces(name, cat, add, lat, lng) {
  return this.places.set({
            placeID: this.placeID,
            placeName: name,
            placeCat: cat,
            placeAdd: add,
            authorID: this.uid,
            author: this.username,
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            rating: 0.5, 
            listDate: firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
        });
    }
```

What Is it am doing wrong? How can I catch the angularfire2 return catch error in a promise and prevent my page from refreshing.

Comment: How and where are you intentionally throwing the error?

Comment: Angularfire is throwing the error as object not found. That is expected behavior but I want to handle it differently when an object is not found